# How to compare two values in a dictionary and return a third one if the condition is satisfied?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, comparison

I'm having some trouble in finding a solution to this problem. I need to compare items belonging to different keys in a dictionary. If the comparison equals my parameter, I need a third (new) element to be inserted in a new key on this very same dictionary. Below is an example of what I intend to do. Hope it makes it easier to understand:

```
A={"names":["jason","peter","mary"],"ages":[25,35,45],"health":["Good","Good","Poor"]}
```

I need to compare each value of `"ages"` with each item of `"health"`, respectively. If the value in `"ages"` is >20 AND the value in `"health"` is `"Good"`, I need to add values `"yes"` or `"no"` to a new key `"fit"` in this dictionary, according to the results of the comparisons carried out before.

I have been looking for all the possible ways to do this, but it didn't work out.

Comment: Sorry, code is missing. Please share your code. How could we help otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in simple way and understand if you are new to python programming. I try to help based on given scenario. @J_H answer is also right.. You can use both answers for your reference.

```
A={"names":["jason","peter","mary"],"ages":[25,35,45],"health": 
["Good","Good","Poor"]}

dicts = {}
age = (A.get("ages"))
health = (A.get("health"))

for i, j in zip(age, health):
    if i > 20 and j == "Good":
        dicts.setdefault("fit", []).append("yes")
    else:
        dicts.setdefault("fit", []).append("no")

print(dicts)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I´m a beginner in python, wasn´t familiar with the zip() function. Solved my problem!

Comment: Welcome bro.. If you want you can upvote the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your data is poorly organized; `zip` can help.

Define a helper predicate:

```
def is_fit(age, health):
    if age > 20 and health == 'Good':
        return 'yes'
    else:
        return 'no'
```

Reorganize the data:

```
import pprint

a = {'names': 'jason peter mary'.split(),
     'ages': [25, 35, 45],
     'health': ['Good', 'Good', 'Poor']}
pprint.pprint(list(zip(a['names'], a['ages'], a['health'])), width=30)

[('jason', 25, 'Good'),
 ('peter', 35, 'Good'),
 ('mary', 45, 'Poor')]
```

Now you're in a position to visit each person's attributes all together:

```
for name, age, health in zip(a['names'], a['ages'], a['health']):
    if is_fit(age, health) == 'yes':
        print(name)
a['fit'] = [is_fit(age, health)
            for age, health
            in zip(a['ages'], a['health'])]
```

Comment: You don't need to iterate over names as you are not using them anywhere, especially in last LC.